# excel vba word matching

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner to excel vba and need help. What function in excel VBA would I use to find a match for a word in a cell? In each cell there are multiple words and to find the specific word what function would be utilized?

I want to write two if statements:
One would find where the word "output" is used and another where "input" is used. Multiple words are in each cell.

Thanks!

Comment: I looked it up but I'm unsure how to use it if there are multiple words in the cell

Comment: Google will tell you that too. SO isn't a VBA tutorial. If you get stuck, come back with the code you have and what issue it's causing.

Comment: Sub MarkText()
    Const Text2Find = "output"
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cel In Selection
        If InStr(cell.Value, Text2Find) > 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your OP/don't put code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *FIND()* method:

```
Sub FindingHappiness()
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range

    s = "happy"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart)
    MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! one last question I had was how you get it to keep running after it finds the first instance of happy?

Comment: @johndoe253  You would use `FindNext` ....................see VBA Help for the syntax, etc.

Comment: thank you for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @johndoe253  You are quite welcome !